# How to move Laravel in hosting?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've been trying to generate my application before I was hosting, but no results,
This is the url of my website : http://blogtest.22web.org

I turn on debug in file ' config/app ' there could be able to find the problem? ...

Comment: Do you have vendor folder in your project ?

Comment: If not run `composer install`

Comment: run `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: @user2486 Yes I have a vendor file, I have the same problem I like him.
want to try a test upload my application on a free hosting server byethost

https://laravelquestions.com/php/laravel-no-application-encryption-key-has-been-specified/,

Comment: @aldrin27 I've try it that way. :(

Comment: heya.. 
could you share the hosting schema? is it shared hosting or a VM? also, how did you migrate the code from your local to the hosting? have you tried the php artisan key:generate and upload the .env to the hosting? how did you place your files?

Comment: @BagusTesa Thanks ,the problem was already met, thank you all for the help :)

Comment: ok, though its weird that it won't read the `.env` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- run php artisan key:generate on your local host this will generate a
  key like this base64:7cXIqdnHzZB3/D0Qg4wWWEXesss70VpCHXaNhA678UA=
- go to config/App.php and place this key in
  'key'=>'base64:7cXIqdnHzZB3/D0Qg4wWWEXesss70VpCHXaNhA678UA='.

  you might get other configuration errors the best way is to setup
  your app via .env configuration. You can read about this on

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration

Comment: Thanks U So mUCH :*  , I do not know why, hosting server there are unwilling to read the configuration of the env, so I settings via config/app

Comment: the above answer may only be able to open the application, but I have more constraints, I'm not able to login. php Connector PDOException in line 55: setting, I need what again? my connection parameters required are correct.

Comment: *I need what again? my connection parameters required are correct.* if it does not read the `.env` you could always specify them in the `config/database.php`.. nevertheless, better to ask it in separate question..

Comment: @BagusTesa Thank you for the application I've run, I just need the configuration settings of the app/database. php. forgive me for not making a mistake this question separately.